# Change default charset to utf-8: mysql

Tags: mysql

I am developing an app in which I am using MySQL database. The database contains certain characters which can not be encoded to the client side & I found those values null. 
Like, a string containing a special character is represented as null at the client side.

I found that the default charset for the db was `latin1`, I changed it to `utf-8`, including all tables and individual columns of those tables. Also in my `pdo_construct` I have mentioned the charset to be utf-8,

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=$dbname;host=$dbhost;charset=utf8',$dbname,$dbhost);
```

I also configured the response headers to use utf-8 charset. But the characters are still not encoded, I am still getting null string in case where the special character is present.

I tried changing the my.ini file configuration by setting the default charset, it gives me error in my connection file at PDO construct.

Its urgent for me to fix this! Can someone help?

Comment: If you didn't restore the database with a dump **with the new utf8 settings**, the data that was in the database before you made your changes will still be latin1. Newly inserted data will be in utf8.